# Jquery get matched class

Tags: jquery, regex, match

I have some html divs with this classes:

```
<div class="nav icon-home nav_header"></div>
<div class="nav icon-address nav_header"></div>
<div class="nav icon-car nav_header"></div>
<div class="nav icon-info nav_header"></div>
<div class="nav icon-user nav_header"></div>
```

I want to use jquery to get the icon class name.

I tried this code:
`jQuery('.nav_header').each(function() {
    var icon_class = jQuery(this).attr('class').match(/icon-*/);
    console.log( icon_class ); 
});`

But it returns the div object.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Change `nav_header` to `.nav_header`. Also you can't run `match` on an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your updated question, you just need to fix your regex to match on anything other than a whitespace

```js
jQuery('.nav_header').each(function() {
    var icon_class = jQuery(this).attr('class').match(/icon-[^ ]+/);
    console.log( icon_class[0] ); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav icon-home nav_header"></div>
<div class="nav icon-address nav_header"></div>
<div class="nav icon-car nav_header"></div>
<div class="nav icon-info nav_header"></div>
<div class="nav icon-user nav_header"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('div').click(function() {
var divClass = $(this).attr('class');
divArr = JSON.stringify(divClass).split(" ");
console.log(divArr[1]);
})
```

Not sure when you wanted to capture the class or how, but you should be able to build off of this.